# How do I recover missing polygons using a UV MAP

Tags: uv

How do I recover missing polygons ( every 5th poly is gone) but I have the .PNG UV Map that has all polys in the right places? How do I import the UV MAP?

Comment: Can you post screenshots/upload a .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)? As it stands, we do not have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to reconstruct missing polygons with only the help of a UV map. The UV map contains not all necessary information about the vertices' location within the 3D coordinate system.

You might be able to close holes in a mesh with Blender's "fill holes" function, but that most possibly requires you to reconstruct the UV map as well.

[image]